# Word change on hover using CSS, JavaScript, or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently working on a project where I would like a **specific word (example: about)** within a paragraph to change to a **different word (example: abut)** when you hover on the **original word "about"**.

The purpose of creating a word change (when hovering over that word) would be for a web visitor to see the original [spelling of a] word from an old document when they hovered over a word, versus just reading the edited version.

I've played around a little with this in simple CSS (CodePen example here: https://codepen.io/LeahS/pen/LmvKZa), but would like to know the best way to create a word change as mentioned above. Is there a way with just CSS? Or is it better with jQuery or Javascript? I currently only know rough JavaScript and jQuery, but will learn both if it helps.

Appreciate your answers and insights, and thank you for taking time to comment.

Notes:

1: There would be multiple words that must be changed per paragraph, and multiple (more than 100+) paragraphs. If at all possible, I would NOT like to create unique CSS classes for each word...

2: I am/would like to use WordPress.

3: I am a beginner.

CodePen code:

```
<style>
.quote:hover .update, .quote .orig {
  display: none;
}
.quote:hover .orig {
  display: inline-block;
}
.quote .update {
  color: blue;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.quote .orig {
  font-style: italic;
}

</style>

<div>We went
<span class="quote">
<spell class="update">about</spell>
<spell class="orig">abut</spell>
</span>
our
<span class="quote">
<spell class="update">business</spell>
<spell class="orig">busness</spell>
</span>
.
</div>
```

Comment: Well, just glancing at your css `.quote:hover` is defining a rule when the user hovers over the quote, not necessarily the update or orig.  The only issue with performing this with css only, is as soon as you hover and hide the original, hiding causes the hover to end, so it will show again, and then hide again, and show again, and ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use data attributes and CSS to display the two different words.

```css
span[data-spell] {
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted gray;
  cursor: help;
}

span[data-spell]::before,
span[data-spell]::after {
  display: none;
}

span[data-spell]::before {
  content: attr(data-spell);
}

span[data-spell]::after {
  content: attr(data-original);
}

span[data-original]:not(:hover)::before,
span[data-spell]:hover::after {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="quote">
  We went <span data-spell="about" data-original="abut"></span> our <span data-spell="business" data-original="busness"></span>.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap both elements in a span, and drive the hover off of that element, so that the hiding of the children does not affect the hover state.

```css
.swappable .orig { display: none; }
.swappable:hover .orig { display: inline-block; }
.swappable:hover .update { display: none; }

.swappable { color: blue; }
```

```html
<div class="quote">
  <div>We went
    <span class="swappable">
      <spell class="update">about</spell>
      <spell class="orig">abut</spell>
    </span> our
    <span class="swappable">
      <spell class="update">business</spell>
      <spell class="orig">busness</spell>
    </span> .
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a couple of changes to the html to make it work, and had both versions of the spelling be within the same span called "change". It's far from perfect but I suppose it's a start?

```css
.changed:hover .update {
  display: none;
}
.changed:hover .orig {
  display: inline-block;
}
.quote .update {
  color: blue;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.quote .orig {
  font-style: italic;
  display:none;
}
.changed {
cursor:pointer
}
```

```html
<div class="quote">
<div>We went
<span class="changed"><spell class="update">about</spell><spell class="orig">abut</spell></span>
our
<span class="changed"><spell class="update">business</spell><spell class="orig">busness</spell></span>
.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Showing the other word with plain, vanilla CSS, based on your provided HTML code is as simple as:

```
spell.update:hover + spell.orig, spell.orig:hover {
 display:inline-block;
}
```

If you want to hide the updated spelling when they're looking at the original, you might find it helpful to enclose both in a span, so you can do the following:

```
span.spelling-container:hover>.orig {
 display:inline-block;
}
span.spelling-container:hover>.update {
 display:none;
}
```